# how can we find elements using xpath without tag name?

Tags: html, xpath

I'm looking to find all elements with a specific class, there can be multiple type of tags with that class name. Suppose I have div s, span s, p s, with same class and I need to find all of them based on class. How can i do it.

I tried:

```
//[contains(@class,'x')]
```

this doesn't work. Please suggest how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
//*[@class="x"]
```

Comment: Well I don't know if it's a miracle but I find you always giving answer's on the posts on which I am giving, its funny! :P Isn't it? :D

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I give answers on almost all sensible CSS questions, you can see my profile :D

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui btw you are just 13 and that's impressive :)

Comment: That does not work for space separated classes. so `class="big red box"` would not match.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I am doing it from 7 :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui that's really great :)

Comment: @Anthony looking at the op's code, I think he is interested to target elements with only class x

Comment: @Mr.Alien I like to work for someone and I am on fiverr please promote my talent :P :D

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Sure, let me know if you need any help, busy these days with the office thingy but whenever you need any help you can tell me..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]
```

You should use `*` to get `all` the elements.

Resource: [XPath Select Element by Class](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/XPath%3a%20Select%20element%20by%20class.htm)

Comment: `' $classname '` is a literal string, not a concatenation of spaces with the value of the `$classname` variable.